# Multiple arrays count comparison C#

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, lambda, arraylist

What is best way to return the count of the smallest/largest array in C# 4.0? preferably using Lambda expressions.

I'm looking for a way to return the count of the smallest array within a list of arrays which would usually contain 5-10 elements. I could go for the usual foreach array > get count > if larger > override > next.. etc. but was hoping for a one-line solution using LINQ/Lambda.

Comment: What do you mean by count for array? Its length? Sum of it elements?

Comment: @VMAtm Array1.Count = 14, Array2.Count = 5, Array3.Count = 9, result of what I'm after is 14 (in case of largest)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var min = arrays.Min(x => x.Length);
```

That will find the length of each array, and return the minimum length. If that's not what you're after, please clarify your question with an example.